# How to get the cookies after adding the cookies in next request in asp.net Mvc ? cookies shows null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a shopping cart application. while adding the product in cart, create the cookies as cartId, here the problem occurs is every time i am adding the product, it will create a new cart Id. whats wrong here.

```
    private readonly string _CartItemId;
    public ShoppingServices(HttpContextBase httpContext) 
        :  this(httpContext,new PaymentGateway())
    {

    }
    public ShoppingServices( HttpContextBase httpContext,PaymentGateway _paymentGateway)
    {

        _dbcontext = _paymentGateway;
        _CartItemId = GetCartId(httpContext);

    }

    private string GetCartId(HttpContextBase http)
    {

        var cookie = http.Request.Cookies.Get("ShoppingCart");
        var cartID = String.Empty;

        if (cookie == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cookie.Value))
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie("ShoppingCart");
            cartID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            cookie.Value = cartID;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);

            http.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
        else
        {
            cartID = cookie.Value;
        }
        return cartID;
```

while adding the product first time, it will create a new cartid and save in cookie ,when reloading and adding another product i am not able to get the cookie. it shows null that what its creating new guid again .

var cookie = http.Request.Cookies.Get("ShoppingCart");

Why it shows null.help me someone?

here i adding the product:

In add product method,cartId= _cartId,which means   creating th guid in that and store to cookie.

First request it create a guid and add the product .

Next request i am not able to get the cookie ,so again it create a new cookie.

How to get the cookie ?

```
public  void AddToCart(int productid)
        {
            var product = _dbcontext.Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == productid);

            if (product == null)
            {



            }

            var cartItem = _dbcontext.Carts.SingleOrDefault(c => c.productId == productid && c.CartID == _CartItemId);

            if (cartItem != null)
            {
                cartItem.count++;

            }

            else
            {
                cartItem = new Cart
                {

                    productId = productid,
                    CartID = _CartItemId,
                    count = 1,
                    Name = DateTime.Now,

                };

                _dbcontext.Carts.Add(cartItem);

            }
            _dbcontext.SaveChanges();



        }
```

}

in the cart table i have cartid and product id , my question if i add the cookie in httpcookie object, it will remain it know,why it shows null.

Comment: I don't think you're using the cookie collection, that's why it returns null.

Comment: Its either a problem with your code that writes to the cookie or the code that retrieves the cookie. To narrow it down: Do you see the cookie in your browser after the first time you add it or does your cookie collection stay empty in your browser? If the answer is `yes` you see a cookie - then writing is good and reading back is the problem. Otherwise its the initial write that is failing.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/6797350/asp-net-mvc-cookie-implementation

Comment: @igor after adding the cookie i am not able to see that cookie in browser, i changed the browser settings still not getting the cookie , but cookie is added .

Comment: @MohamedSahir - see the link that Madagaga posted. Here is the url again so you can click on it. [ASP.NET MVC Cookie Implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6810953/1260204)

Comment: http://blog.codeinside.eu/2010/10/19/howto-create-and-remove-cookies-with-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: anyway thanks @Igor somewhat confusing this topic. .